# Is it bad practice for a link using a click handler and window.location.replace to also have the same location as the href?

Tags: javascript, html

So on our page we have a "Quick exit" button (really a link styled as a button), which takes you to Google. We wanted to keep it simple in terms of functionality, but we decided it would probably be a good idea to at least use window.location.replace for navigation to prevent browser back, so we're using a click handler. However I thought it might also be a good idea to add href="https://google.com" simply so that the user will be able to see where the button is going if they hover over it. But, I'm just not sure if this would be violating some unwritten rule, since technically the href isn't doing anything, and is only there to "trick" the user into thinking they're clicking a normal link when it's really running JavaScript. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to prevent default browser back behavior (which some consider user-unfriendly), then what you're doing is perfectly reasonable, and could even be better than the alternatives. It not only gives the user an indication of what clicking will do, it'll also allow those few users with JavaScript disabled to navigate your page.

An explicit `href` may also help web scrapers like Googlebot find pages on your site (though this won't matter if the link is external and to some place you don't care about SEO for).